# form validation in spring in action 5

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am following the source code of *spring in action 5* on github, and I code my own version.
When I leave the name blank and commit, I get a wrong page like that

[image]

and the console output is:
`Field error in object 'taco' on field 'name': rejected value [];`

But the correct page is like that:
[image: the taco design page with a warning message aroud the name text box]

here is my code:

design.html

```
 <label>give it a name:</label>

 <input type="text" th:field="*{name}">

  <span class="validationError"
      th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}"
      th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</span>
```

designController.java

```
    @PostMapping
    public String postTaco(@Valid Taco taco, Order order, Errors errors) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()){
            return "design";
        }

        Taco taco1 = tacoRepo.save(taco);
        order.addDesign(taco1);
        return "order";
    }
```

Taco.java

```
@Size(min=5, message = "at least 5 characters")
private String name;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Where is the problem

designContrller.java

```
    @PostMapping
    public String postTaco(@Valid Taco taco, Order order, Errors errors) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()){
            return "design";
        }

        Taco taco1 = tacoRepo.save(taco);
        order.addDesign(taco1);
        return "order";
    }
```

### solution：

```
    @PostMapping
    public String postTaco(@Valid Taco taco, Errors errors, Order order) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()){
            return "design";
        }

        Taco taco1 = tacoRepo.save(taco);
        order.addDesign(taco1);
        return "order";
    }
```

### conclusiong:

The parameter `Erroes errors` must behide the valid object parameter, here is `Taco taco`